# Exclude Rows with 0-values from PivotTable without Helper Column

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
       A             B              C 
                  Quantity      Sales Price
1  Product A        500              0
2  Product A          0           5.95
3  Product A        600          19.95
4  Product B        250              0
5  Product B          0          44.99
6  Product C        700          29.99
```

In **Column A** you can see different products that can appear several times in the list. In **Column B** and **Column C** you can see their quantity and sales price. There can also be cells with value 0.

Now I created a simply **PivotTable** based on this data which gives me the following result:

```
            Count of Quantity
Product A          3
Product B          2
Product C          1
```

As you can see the rows that contain 0 values are also in the count. 
Since I want to exclude them I inserted a "Helper Column" in the original data with the following formula:

```
=IF(OR(B2=0,C2=0),"=0","<>0")
```

This "Helper Column" I use as a **Report Filter** in the PivotTable.

Well, that solution works so far but is there also a way to avoid the "Helper Column" and do the "Exclude 0-Function" directly in the PivotTable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Add Quantity and Sales Price to your Pivot Report Filter Panel.

In the filter, choose all and then remove 0 from both.

Right-Click each filter and choose Field Settings, and tick "Include New Items in Manual Filter".